# Replacement for the discontinued Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000

Tags: wireless, mice, ergonomics

I have a Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 that I bought over 10 years ago. It is a large, wireless, ergonomically-shaped mouse (nearly vertical, but not quite as vertical as the Evoluent VerticalMouse):

| Top view of mouse: | Side view of mouse: |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

This is a fantastic mouse. My original is still going strong after all this time, but as I have more than one computer, I'd like to purchase a second one. **Unfortunately, Microsoft has discontinued this mouse, so I am looking for a worthy replacement.**

Apparently, Microsoft's intended successor is the [Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D68ZVY8). This appears to have a very similar body and build, so is very appealing to me. *However*, it has one serious drawback and one potentially minor flaw:

1. Inferior back/forward navigation buttons. It doesn't have a forward button at all. It does have a back button, but according to reviews, it's recessed, difficult to press (requires curling your thumb up in a very unergonomic way), and positioned right underneath the "Windows" button (which opens the Start menu). According to most reviewers, even after an adjustment period, they still end up accidentally hitting the Windows button when aiming for the back button. I, like most reviewers, don't need a Windows button on my mouse. I'd remap the Windows button, but it seems Microsoft has thought of that and thus completely disabled the ability to remap this button. I absolutely need back and forward navigation buttons, and I need them to be easily accessible with my thumb, as I use these all the time. I *don't* need a Windows key or any other buttons, but I don't mind if they're there, as long as they don't interfere with the use of the back/forward navigation buttons.
2. According to at least one reviewer, the Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse is smaller than the Natural Wireless Laser Mouse. This is a minor flaw. Most mice out there in the world are *far* too small for my hands, but this one isn't actually tiny, and I could learn to live with it, even if it isn't *quite* as big as I'd like, since it's still big enough… If it weren't for the major flaw mentioned above.

Before I shell out an *absurd* amount of money for a ridiculously-overpriced used Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000, can anyone recommend a worthy successor? It must:

- be **vertical** or nearly vertical, to relieve hand strain
- be **large** enough to fill my hand (like the Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 or most any other classic Microsoft IntelliMouse-style mouse, but unlike most other mice on the market today)
- have well-designed, easily accessible **backward and forward navigation buttons** (or buttons that I can remap as such) that are operated with the thumb
- have a **scroll wheel** under the middle finger (just vertical scrolling is sufficient; horizontal tilt is nice)
- be **wireless** (i.e., have no cord; I don't care what kind of wireless technology or how it connects)

I am right-handed (obviously, since the Microsoft Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 is only for right-handed folks). The mouse will primarily be used with Windows machines, but…it's a mouse, so the platform really doesn't matter. I don't care about the brand. It should go without saying that I want a mouse, not a trackpad, trackpoint, trackball, trackcat, or any other "frame challenge".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old post, but I'm in the same boat.   The MS 6000 is my fav all-time mouse and mine died a few years ago.   I've been on the hunt for years to find something like it.

Anker has a decent vertical mouse.  Logitech just put out a new one in 2022.  Both are too light and slippery for my tastes.

I've been using a kinsington expert mouse (bit trackball), it's the closest I can come to comefort.

Curious as to what you would up doing?

Comment: I'm still here, and, unfortunately, still haven't found a solution. I'm still using the one MS Natural Wireless Laser Mouse 6000 that I do have on my main computer, and using some older, non-ergonomic/natural MS Wireless Laser Mice (e.g., the MS Wireless Laser Mouse 5000) on a smattering of other computers. At least they meet all of my requirements other than being vertical. I never got used to trackballs, so I haven't explored those options at all. The new Logitech offering might be interesting... I haven't seen that one.

Comment: Good luck to you, I have the new Logitech, I like everything about it except it's too slick if you often pick up your mouse.   With 6 monitors & a large desk, I often need to

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse is a pretty fair replacement.  They're getting harder to find too tho.

[https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Sculpt-Ergonomic-Mouse-L6V-00001/dp/B00D68ZVY8/ref=sr_1_3?crid=38M56PU07YIS9&keywords=sculpt+mouse&qid=1695949374&s=electronics&sprefix=sculpt+m%2Celectronics%2C109&sr=1-3&ufe=app_do%3Aamzn1.fos.006c50ae-5d4c-4777-9bc0-4513d670b6bc](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D68ZVY8)